# How do i add all values with the same year in list?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of strings that looks something like this :

- 2010  1  11.45
- 2010  2  09.50
- 2010  3  15.00
- .
- .
- .
- 2019  12  11.10

(the list is a list of spends per month between the years of 2010 - 2019)

I have separated the list into 3 lists for each value such as :

```
for(....){

val part = list.get(i).split(" ")
val year = parts[0]
val month = parts[1]
val spend = parts[2]

yearlist.add(year)
monthlist.add(month)
spendlist.add(spend)
}
```

Now my issue is that I want to find the year with the highest spend total. How would I add all of the spends for each year?

I have tried the following method however this gives me an IndexOutOfBounds Exception:

```
var totalspend = 0
for(i in 0..yearlist.size-1){

if(yearlist[i]==yearlist[i+1]){//i get an error here 
    totalspend = totalspend + spendlift[i]
}
else if(yearlist[i]!=yearlist[i+1]){
    totalspend = totalspend + spendlift[i]
    spendforyear.add(totals(year[i], totalspend))
    totalspend = 0.0
}

}
```

I assume the error is because i cant compare the final yearlist value with yearlist[i+1] as i+1 is out of bounds.

How would i go about solving this?

Comment: /shouldnt it be spend = parts[2] ?

Comment: yeah, thats a mistake I made. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest saving the `year`, `month` and `spend` in a `data class` and then use collection functions:

```
data class Report(val year: String, val month: String, val spend: Double)

fun main() {

    val reports = listOf(
        Report("2010", "1", 11.45),
        Report("2010", "2", 09.50),
        Report("2010", "3", 15.00),
        Report("2019", "12", 11.10)
    )
    val groupedReports = reports.groupBy { it.year }
    val mostSpending = groupedReports.maxBy { it.value.sumByDouble { report -> report.spend } }
    println(mostSpending?.key) // year with the most spending
    println(mostSpending?.value?.sumByDouble { it.spend }) // the spending on that year
}
```

Comment: How would i print the spending amount?

Comment: Thats great, Thank you!